# Finding and manually weeding out images in ClusteringComponents clusters

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, image-processing, image

I have processed images using the following code, where `list1` and `list 2` are x and y axes, [sample of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM9pB.png):

```
     images = FileNames["*.png"][[ ;; ]];
imagescrop = ImageAdjust[ImageCrop[#] &/ @ images
      clusters = ClusteringComponents[imagescrop[[ ;; ]], 21, 
       CriterionFunction -> "Dunn"];
    groups = Partition[clusters, 46];
     Flatten[
      Table[Transpose[{list1[[i]], list2[[j]], groups[[i, j]]}], {i, 
        11}, {j, 46}], 1];
    ListDensityPlot[%, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

Output:

[image]

How can I weed out the odd looking pictures inside clusters and identify them, ideally by filename?

Ideal outcome, doesn't have to be same sorting, just cleaner or minimal odd looking regions:

[image]